# Integration Test to webDav client using apache httpclient LocalTestServer

Tags: junit, integration-testing, webdav, apache-httpcomponents

I am trying to write Integrations tests for WebDavClient (based on jackrabbit) using apache httpclient LocalTestServer.
I was inspired from the following [blog](https://thecarlhall.wordpress.com/2010/03/25/unit-testing-with-httpclients-localtestserver/) and written the test below:

```
public class WebDAVClientIT {

    private LocalTestServer server;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception{
        server = new LocalTestServer(null, null);
        server.start();
        //direct all requests to my handelr
        server.register("/*", new WebDavHandler());
    }

    @Test
    public void testUploadFileStringInputStreamString() throws Exception {

        WebDAVClient webDavClient = new WebDAVClient();
        //set the client user/pass etc
        webDavClient.init();

        byte[] data = "123,456,789,123,456,789".getBytes();
        InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        Status uploadFileStatus = webDavClient.uploadFile("test/file.csv", input, "text/csv");
        assertThat(uploadFileStatus.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED));

    }

    @After
    public void distory() throws Exception {
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

I created a request handler that will make the server feel like a WebDav server.

```
public class WebDavHandler implements HttpRequestHandler {
        private Map<String, String> resources;
        public WebDavHandler() {
            //map existing resources 
            resources = new HashMap<>();
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response,
                HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
            RequestLine requestLine = request.getRequestLine();
            String method = requestLine.getMethod();
            String uri = request.getRequestLine().getUri();

            switch (method) {
            case "GET":
                if (resources.containsKey(uri)) {
                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
                } else {
                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_NOT_FOUND);
                }
                break;
            case "MKCOL":
                if (resources.containsKey(uri)) {
                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
                } else {
                    response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED);
                    resources.put(uri, uri);
                }
                break;
            }
            logger.info("Executing " + request);
        }

    }
```

Now my problem is that LocalTestServer is not a real WebDav server and some of the methods supported by WebDav will not be supported by LocalTestServer e.g. MkColMethod

```
[statusCode=501, statusText=Internal Server Error, responseString=MKCOL method not supported]
```

How do I extend the LocalTestServer to emulate webdav missing methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject a custom connection factory, which is aware of extra request methods.

Please note I used HttpClient 4.4 to put together this example.

```
public class TestDAV extends LocalServerTestBase {

    @Before @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new DefaultHttpRequestFactory() {
            @Override
            public HttpRequest newHttpRequest(final RequestLine requestline) throws MethodNotSupportedException {
                if (requestline.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("BLAH")) {
                    return new BasicHttpRequest(requestline);
                }
                return super.newHttpRequest(requestline);
            }
        };
        HttpMessageParserFactory<HttpRequest> requestParserFactory = new DefaultHttpRequestParserFactory(
                BasicLineParser.INSTANCE, requestFactory);
        DefaultBHttpServerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DefaultBHttpServerConnectionFactory(
                ConnectionConfig.DEFAULT, requestParserFactory, DefaultHttpResponseWriterFactory.INSTANCE);
        this.serverBootstrap.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBlah() throws Exception {

        this.serverBootstrap.registerHandler("/stuff", new HttpRequestHandler() {
            @Override
            public void handle(
                    final HttpRequest request,
                    final HttpResponse response,
                    final HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {
                response.setEntity(new StringEntity("Blah", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
            }
        });

        final HttpHost target = start();
        final HttpRequest get = new BasicHttpRequest("BLAH", "/stuff");
        final CloseableHttpResponse response = this.httpclient.execute(target, get);
        try {
            Assert.assertEquals(200, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
            EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I am   using httpclient 4.3.1 and fail to compile your example, looking at the source code of 4.4 their is  a big difference. Is is possible to use 4.3?

Comment: It should be possible. 4.4 just makes it more convenient.

Comment: I failed for find how to set the connectionFactory

Comment: I had a closer look at 4.3 test code. There is no way one can replace the connection factory of the test server without forking the source. Please consider upgrading to HC 4.4

Comment: Thanks oleg for your effort. I can not use 4.4 before GA. Appreciate your effort.

Comment: Suit yourself. 4.4 GA by the way can be expected by the end of the week

Comment: Vote up for the effort :-)

Comment: When 4.4 had become GA I added it as a test dependency and it did the trick, thanks :-)